# E0349:no operator "=" matches these operands when using JSON using nlohmann-json

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio, nlohmann-json

I'm using `nlohmann-json` on my C++ project on Visual Studio and I caught an error of

```
E0349:no operator "=" matches these operands
```

at the code below:

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
using json = nlohmann::json;


void myFunc(unsigned int** arr) {
    json j;
    j["myArr"] = arr;//E0349:no operator "=" matches these operands
}
```

What is wrong ?

On the other hand, when I try the following one, it works.

```
void myFunc(unsigned int** arr) {
    json j;
    j["myArr"] = {1,2,3};// no error
}
```

I'm guessing this is attributed to data-type problem.

I would appreciate any information.

Comment: It's quite simple really. A pointer is not an array. And an array is not a pointer.

Comment: I think nlohmann-json only supports creating arrays from c++ containers. Note that you're second example isn't an array, it's an initialiser list

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize the difference between pointer and array. I would like to try using array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nlohmann json only supports creating arrays from c++ standard library containers. It wouldn't be possible to create an array from a pointer as it has no information about the size of the array.

If you have c++20 then you can use [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) to convert your pointer (and a size) into a container:

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <span>

using json = nlohmann::json;


void myFunc(unsigned int* arr, size_t size) {
    json j;
    j["myArr"] = std::span(arr, size);
}
```

If you don't have c++20 you would have to either implement `std::span` yourself or copy your array into something like `std::vector` (or just use `std::vector` to start with rather than raw arrays).

Alternatively construct the array manually (you still need a size here):

```
void myFunc(unsigned int* arr, size_t size) {
    json j;
    auto& myArr = j["myArr"];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        myArr.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize the difference between pointer and array. I would like to try your demonstrations.